# What is happening at the gate of a JFET to cause an electric field?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism, semiconductors, jfet, electrostatic

I am reading "Practical Electronics for Inventers" 4th edition and came across this circuit.

[image]

As I understand, for a JFET, current will flow from drain to source for a n-channel (opposite for p-channel), and when you reverse bias the pn-junction you create a depletion region. Since an electric field is created when some voltage is applied to the gate this modifies the width and shape of that depletion region in the JFET. The implication as I understand is that this affects the conductivity of the channel between the source and drain.

My question as it relates to this circuit is, if you have some charged object that acquired more negative charges, what is happening in the wire on the gate that is generating changing the electric field?

My guess is that the the electric field is increased for a n-channel JFET at the gate since the electrons will move through the wire and should fill the holes at the p-channel. Is that correct? I'm not sure what the meter should read so any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "field increased", do you mean in terms of magnitude? Electric field has direction, it is a vector quantity: it must specify orientation as well as amount. Perhaps you would be better off considering a scalar quantity, such as the voltage at the gate pin?